# Inconsistent operation of driver.findElements in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I cant find a logical answer myself with how selenium webdriver locates elements in a webpage. I was trying to iterate rows (cell-values) of particular column and found out this.

```
 <table id="Results"> 
       <tr> <td id="item"> Apple </td> <td> 10 </td> </tr>
       <tr> <td id="item"> Ball  </td> <td> 20 </td> </tr> 
       <tr> <td id="item"> Cat   </td> <td> 30 </td> </tr>
 <table>
```

I just need to extract only Apple, Ball and Cat and hence used below approach,

```
1: List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='Results']//tr”));
2: for(WebElement row : rows){
3:   List<WebElement> cells = row.findElements(By.xpath("//td[@id='item']"));
4:   for(WebElement cell : cells){
5:      System.out.println(cell.getText);
6:   }
7: }

Output:
Apple
Apple
Apple
```

But after changing Line#: 3 with,

```
3:   List<WebElement> cells = row.findElements(By.xpath(".//td[@id='item']"));

Output:
Apple
Ball
Cat
```

So, the point i dont understand here is, why didn't i get correct result with my first approach as i was trying to query child elements using parent node? Instead a "." in second approach resolved the issue. What is exactly happening here and logic behind this?

Comment: can you please tell me how your first approach worked cause i see various issue in it first xpath is incorrect ,second how can you apply for loop on single element also u have not used any findElements any where also i want to know just by changing line 3 it worked for you it should not work in any condition if above is your exact code

Comment: your xpath is worng .. it is //table[@id='Results'//tr instead of //table[@id='Results']//tr

Comment: @rajNishKuMar, i have corrected my typos, please revisit and provide me your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't specify the start node, it will start from root. In this case, `//td[@id='item']` will find elements from `/html` which means it might find others elements. As you mentioned in the second approach, you have to use `.//td[@id='item']` so it will start from current node which is `row`.

Comment: Exactly, i understand that. But whats the use of calling findElements using webElement reference, i.e., `row.findElements`? i could have used `driver.findElements` if my purpose is to get all td elements from html right?

Comment: Here is the use `.//td[@id='item']`. You can't do this with `driver.findElements`.

Comment: Thanks @Buaban, i got it now. I think only u understood my exact ask! I would still consider findElements as inconsistent as both `driver.findElements()` and `row.findElements()` behaves same way.

Answer (score 0):

I think your second approach is not correct also. Since you can't assign a list of WebElements to WebElement. You will get a compilation error. If you want to have the desired output then use the code snippet below:

```
        List<WebElement> cells = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='item']"));

        for(WebElement cell : cells){
            System.out.println(cell.getText());
        }
```

Think that you understand.

Comment: It was a typo in my original post. I corrected it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you specify '//', the xpath will start searching for that node irrespective of its parent node, on the complete xml and returns the first element which it encounters, which in this case 'Apple' every time.

If you specify './/', the xpath will start searching for that element which is present under the context node (tr in this case), which mean, it would not search for td element in the complete xml every time. It will search for the descendants of the context node. In this case, it will return the value for every td node present under tr node.

Hope this helps. Please let me know if you need more information on that.

Comment: Karthik, then why should Selenium support the method WebElement.findElements, if result is same as Driver.findElements. I am doing lookup based on my ParentNode reference and not by using Driver object, but all i get is same answer. <br/> Let me give you a real world scenario: In my team, 1 Manager --> 3 Team Leads --> 15 Testers (5 Testers reporting to each lead). If i ask my Manager(Driver) how many testers in team, he would say 15, but if i ask Team Lead#1 (row / ParentNode), then he SHOULD say 5, not 15.

Comment: Bhuvanesh, If you want to restrict your xpath to search the descendants of a particular webelement we can use WebElement.findElements. If you dont want restriction we can use driver.findElements. Now coming to the output of the commands, it will completely depend on the xml of your application. If your xml contains two tables with the same id as "//table[@id='Results']//tr", driver.webelements will give you 2 tables, whereas webelement.findElements will return you only one table. Even in this case, if you use xpath which identifies only one table, then both commands will return same result.